# Value Error: item not in list. 2D array/list, I'm completely stuck

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

When this section is run, it returns `Value Error: item not in list.`
I am trying to search for a specific number in column 5 of the csv, and then print the row where it is located. The number I am entering is definitely in the list. Any help?

```
def borrowing():
    id = (raw_input("What is the OCLC of the book being borrowed?\n"))
    while True:
        try:
            id = int(id) #changes id to int, must be changed back to str.
            break
        except ValueError:
            id = (raw_input("Enter the OCLC with numbers only: \n"))
    id = str(id)
    x = open('bl.csv','rU')
    reader = list(csv.reader(x))
    index = reader.index(id)
    if info(index) == id:
        y = info[index]
        print "The following has been found:",y
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with leading zeros in the id number? '01' is not '1'. Instead of `id = int(id)` it's enough to write `int(id)`. Then you won't have to use `str` to convert it back, and it would prevent such a problem.

Comment: So I can just remove the id = str(id) line? If so this does not work.

Comment: yup, but only if you replace `id = int(id)` with `int(id)`

Comment: Yeah I have done that but it has not visibly changed anything.

Comment: Because it's not the problem. It might be a problem in the future, but right now what's causing the exception is that `reader` is a two-dimensional array (`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]...]`), so `.index()` will compare the id to arrays and not to strings (as people have said in the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is at this line `index = reader.index(id)`.

The reader actually returns a list with all the rows as nested lists. So, to actually get an index from the `reader`, you should pass an entire row like this.

```
index = myreader.index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'])
```

But if you are looking for a particular attribute then you should probably do something like this.

```
def borrowing():
    id = (raw_input("What is the OCLC of the book being borrowed?\n"))
    while True:
        try:
            id = int(id) #changes id to int, must be changed back to str.
            break
        except ValueError:
            id = (raw_input("Enter the OCLC with numbers only: \n"))
    id = str(id)
    x = open('bl.csv','rU')
    reader = list(csv.reader(x))
    id = str(id)
    x = open('bl.csv','rU')
    reader = list(csv.reader(x))
    index = 0
    for ind, item in enumerate(myreader):
        if id in item:
            index = ind
            print 'Found it'
            print ind+1,': This is row number'#Because index start with 0
    print index #Here it is. Assigned!!!
```

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to direct me as to where I should implement this in my code, as I am new to python.

Comment: Is 'ind' index? or literally ind

Comment: It is index. As you already have a variable index, I gave a different name. Just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh right, my bad, sorry. I will try this now, thank you.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this, would you be able to paste my code into you answer with the suggested edit. Sorry about this.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, how would I assign the found row to a variable?

Comment: Never mind I have figured it out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when asking for help you should post the full error message you are getting.

Now, I'm guessing that your problem comes from the following two lines of code:

```
reader = list(csv.reader(x))
index = reader.index(id)
```

`reader` contains a list of lists (each row is a list of strings), and `reader.index(id)` of course won't find anything.

You would have to iterate over `reader` like this:

```
for n, row in enumerate(reader):
  if row[4] == id:
    print n, row
```

And by the way, there is no need for the `reader` list. You can directly iterate over the result of `csv.reader()`:

```
for n, row in enumerate(csv.reader(x)):
  ...
```

Comment: What does row[4] specify?

Comment: @ScottMiller column 5 in the current row. Each row is a list [col1, col2, col3, ...], and to get at column 5, you need to access row[4].

Answer (score 1):

csv.reader converted to a list is 2-dimensional. The first dimension is rows, and second is columns. So you can't find 5 in it.